# Cannot read property 'id' of null if object Null using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve data by using ajax and successfully the data appears, but there is my problem when data is not there I want to try to change its value, but it fails what is wrong with my script? and its error message is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null //this error 

    $('[name="changeID"]').change(function () {
        var url = base_url+'tools/get_id';
        var idTools = $('[name="number_tools"]').val();

        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { id : idTools},
                    success: function(data) { 
                        var result = data.id;
                        var getNewID = parseInt(result.substr(result.length -3)) + 1;

                        if (!data) {
                            $('[name="id"]').val("000"); //error here                               
                        }else{
                            $('[name="id"]').val(getNewID);                             
                        }
                        console.log(result);
                    },
                    error: function (request, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                        console.log(request.responseText);
                    }
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: The parameter `data` is `null`. What is the value you are intending to give via your URL?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorekso if data there is data it will appear ID_A but if data does not exist or not found it will show ID_B

Comment: You can add a condition such as `if(data != null) { /* Data was returned */ } else { /* No data returned */ }`.

Comment: still error his results. my result json if true, {  "id": "GT-MPT-057" }

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek condition is correct, but @irwan wants to change id if  `data` is null and he is abstracting id from the `data` . am I right @irwan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ajax response to below format,

```
if(!data) 
{ 
     $('[name="id"]').val("000"); 
}
else
{ 
     var result = data.id;.                   
     var getNewID = parseInt(result.substr(result.length -3)) + 1;
     $('[name="id"]').val(getNewID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are use `data` object before checking null. If `data` is null then obviously you will get error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`. You have to use data in `if (!data) { }` condition.

Comment: so how is the solution

Comment: What you have to achieve if the `data` from the ajax call is null? And what if `data` from the ajax call is not null?